# How to assign concatenated jQuery formed html to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, concatenation

I have `$("div").attr("id", "test")` and `$("<span>")`. I want to concatenate them and assign it to a variable.

```
var test = $("<div>").attr("style", "color:red").addClass("test")+$("<span>");
$("body").append(test);​ //gives [object Object][object Object]

test += $("div"); //also want to do like this
```

JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zkSEw/1/) showing what i have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot *concat* jQuery objects with the plus operator. But jQuery offers the `.add()` method which allows you to add more *elements* into an existing wrapped set.

```
var test = $("<div>").attr("style", "color:red").addClass("test");

test.add( $("<span>") );
test.add( $("<div>") );
```

Now you can operate on all those elements like

```
test.appendTo( document.body );
```

---

See: http://api.jquery.com/add/